# Create login with regex from First Middle Last

Tags: regex

I have a file with usernames as such: FirstName Middle LastName

I'm trying to use regex to get FMLastName

I have managed to get FLastName using a replace of $1$4 with the following regex:  ([a-zA-Z]{1})(.+)( )(.+)

I'm new to regex and I'm finding it very complex. Would someone have an idea on how to get FMLastName?

Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

JM

Comment: Are you sure there are always 3 parts present? Are these names always in English and have no accented chars? What is the regex flavor?

Comment: At the current time they will always be in English

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to use the first letter from first and middle names, then you can try below regex:

```
(\w)\w+ (\w)\w+ (\w*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wHCXLr/1)

Comment: It resolves the issue unless there is junk in the incoming data, or there are 4+ parts in the names.